# Application lost the surface error, Android Studio - Google Glass

Tags: android, android-studio, google-glass, google-glass-camera

I'm a beginner on Android Studio. I make the Google Glass Application to record video. I received 'Application lost the surface' error. I tried some solutions, but I could not resolve this error.
This is my Google Glass App Code.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.WindowManager;

@SuppressLint("Registered")
public class VideoActivity extends Activity {
    String fileOutput = "DCIM/Camera/imgtest.mp4";
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + fileOutput;
    private android.hardware.Camera mCamera;
    //private Camera mCamera;
    private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;

    /*SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceCallback = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            try
            {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            if (mCamera != null)
            {
                try {
                    mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
                    parameters.setPreviewSize(640, 360);
                    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
                    mCamera.startPreview();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            if (mCamera != null)
            {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                //mCamera = null;
            }
        }
    };*/

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.preview);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        SurfaceView mPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.preview);
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        Recording(mPreview);
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.release();
        }
    }

    private void Recording (SurfaceView view)
    {
        if (mediaRecorder != null) {
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            mediaRecorder.release();
            mediaRecorder = null;
        }
        try {
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            SurfaceHolder mHolder = view.getHolder();
            //mHolder.addCallback(surfaceCallback);
            Surface surface = mHolder.getSurface();
            //SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(0);
            mediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
            mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
            mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
            mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(1000);
            mediaRecorder.setCaptureRate(15);
            mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(15);
            //mCamera.setPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);
            mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surface);
            mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(path);
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
            mediaRecorder.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is error code.

```
E/MediaRecorderJNI: Application lost the surface
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: invalid preview surface
                  at android.media.MediaRecorder._prepare(Native Method)
                  at android.media.MediaRecorder.prepare(MediaRecorder.java:739)
                  at com.example.glass.transfer1.VideoActivity.Recording(VideoActivity.java:102)
                  at com.example.glass.transfer1.VideoActivity.onCreate(VideoActivity.java:72)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5236)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1089)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2285)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1236)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5061)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I don't know why this error is appeared. I added SurfaceHolder and Surface in Recording, but the application lost the surface. How can I fix this error? Thank you.